# How can I import my fixtures inside a model?

Tags: cakephp, phpunit

I recently started writing unit tests (I am following the tutorial on cakephp cookbook) on some old code and came across a problem.

A model imports another model with `App::import('Model', 'Model2')` and `new Model2()` or `ClassRegistry::init('Model2')`. I made a fixture for both models, but Model2 still uses the default model.

Can someone give me some pointers about how to deal with this?

I've been looking online for some examples, but apparently cakephp2 is hardly used anymore let alone in accordance with phpunit.

**Model**

```
App::uses('Credit', 'Model');

class Credit extends AppModel {

  public function transfer_credits($from_comp, $from_user, $to_comp, $to_user, $credits) {
    App::import('Model', 'CreditTransfer');
    $CreditTransfer = ClassRegistry::init('CreditTransfer');
    $CreditTransfer->save($data);
  }

}
```

**Test**

```
class CreditTest extends CakeTestCase {

  public $fixures = array('app.credit','app.credit_transfer');

  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->Credit = ClassRegistry::init('Credit');
    $this->Credit->useDbConfig = 'test';
    $this->CreditTransfer = ClassRegistry::init('CreditTransfer');
    $this->CreditTransfer->useDbConfig = 'test';
  }

  public function testTransferCreditsValid() {
    $credit_tranfers_before = $this->CreditTransfer->find('count');
    $result = $this->Credit->transfer_credits(1, 1, 2, 2, 5);
    $credit_tranfers_after = $this->CreditTransfer->find('count');

    $this->assertEqual($credit_tranfers_before + 1, $credit_tranfers_after);
  }

}
```

So, in conclusion: `Model1` imports `Model2`. 
`Model2` goes to real database instead of using fixture.

Comment: Please post your actual code (and include whatever `Model2` is too), even if it would be only the involved model's names! Using dummy code always involves the possibility of cloaking the problem because something's missing/different. Generally all models obtained via `ClassRegistry::init()` should automatically have a test connection applied (ie no need to do that manually in your test): **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.10.16/lib/Cake/Utility/ClassRegistry.php#L151-L167**.

Comment: @ndm, I adjusted the question. The methods are abridged, but these are my actual model / method names.